# Post Share in LinkedIn using Java API

Tags: linkedin-api, spring-social, linkedin-j

There is a requirement to post link (Image + Hyperlink + Text) in linkedin Group using Java. I tried following to achieve this.

**Using LinkedinJ API:**
-> There is only one method for sharing a post in group,

```
 LinkedInApiClient.createPost("GROUPID","POST TITLE","POST MESSAGE");
```

-> But there is no support for posting a link in Group.
-> We can post link in account wall using

LinkedInApiClient.postShare("POST TITLE", "LINK TITLE", "POST MESSAGE", "LINK URL", "IMAGE URL", VisibilityType.ANYONE);

**Using SpringSocial-LinkedIn API:**
-> In spring API there is one method to post in group,

linkedin.groupOperations().createPost(GROUPID,"POST TITLE","POST MESSAGE");

-> But, there is no method to post link in LinkedIn group.

Manually there is a way to post link in the group. The following are the steps.

1) Post share in the account first. 

2) Share the post in the linked in group.

The following are the questions?

1) Way to achieve the above functionality?

2) Way to get the post id using API?

3) Alternate way to post link in LinkedIn group?

Thanks,